# Custom Game Engine - Draw Zelda Map With 2D Array

Tags: c#, game-engine

I am now four months into my game development study and we got an assignment where we have to draw 4 animated characters by loading them in as bitmaps and draw a little map of one of the very first zelda games. Now I got the animated sprites to work, I am just not so sure about the map. To clarify things, this is what your canvas should look like when you run the code(the sprites you see are animated but obviously you can't see that on a picture):

[image]

We have to draw the map by using a single spritesheet that contains all the blocks of the map and you can draw it by cutting out a small piece of the spritesheet:

[image]

Our teacher told us that we should be able to do this using a 2D array but I have no clue how that would work.

What I have been able to do so far is create a new bitmap and load the bitmap. Then I drew the first 2 forest rows with a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            GAME_ENGINE.DrawBitmap(Link_Level, 128 + (i * 32), 0, 32, 96, 32, 32);
            GAME_ENGINE.DrawBitmap(Link_Level, 128 + (i * 32), 32, 32, 96, 32, 32);
        }
```

I know that the most simple way is to draw the map block by block but that would take a long time and I am looking for a way to make it work with a 2D array.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

P.S. We are writing this in C# in visual studio 2015

Comment: I still don't understand what you're asking. Are you trying to store all the map sprites in a 2d array?

Comment: You did not ask a question (hint: use at least one question mark). Give it a try and if you encounter a problem, come here with your best try as a [mcve] and a good description of where your problem is.

Comment: For a starting point, imagine assigning each tile in that spritesheet (assuming the spooky-looking tree is really 6 tiles) a number. The staircase is 0, the corner of the grass is 11. The blue liney thing is 12, the right side of the grass is 23. Through division and modulus operators, you should be able to write a function that takes an input like "20" and works out which tile on the sheet it's corresponding to, then calls GAME_ENGINE.DrawBitmap for it. Then, set up your level so that it's a 2D array containing a whole bunch of those numbers.

Comment: @Katana314 Thanks for the replies, This could indeed work but how would I tell the program where on the screen to draw the tile?

Comment: @S.Neut - you always draw off screen either a vertical column or horizontal row. Never on the screen unless it's first render. Know what I mean? You don't refresh the whole thing. So if your character is always 'center of screen', you know the x and y coordinate of the screen you are displaying. You bit shift that down , and the width , to get the position in the 'block map' (see below)

Comment: @S.Neut In other words your tile position on first render is going to be block map position * 32 (or 16 or whatever) + offset relative to where character is

Comment: @Sentinel hmm, I'm still not sure how you tell the program on what coördinates you want to draw part of the spritesheet. I get that with an array you can assign numbers to all the tiles on the spritesheet but when you draw it you have to give it x and y coördinates to draw it on the screen

Comment: @S. Neut. Where's the problem? It's totally easy. If your blockmap points to 16*16 tiles on the spritesheet, then every blockmap number means 16*16 pixels on your screen. If your blockmap is 1000 blocks wide, your 'world' is 16000 pixels wide. If your screen is 1280 pixels wide, that's 80 blocks wide (80*16 =1280)If your character is in the middle of the screen and at X position 4000 in the 'world'. hen the left boundary of your screen is 4000-640.So your left block is (4000-640)/16. Or what you could do is prerender the whole world and just pan your window on the world if you have enough mem.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah what your teacher is referring to is called a "Block Map". This is the 2d array. The historical reasons for all this stuff is that it was fast using assembler to bitshift the values in the block map to get a physical address to read the sprite data (and write).

So what you do is divide your single spritesheet into say 32x32 or 16x16 chunks. Then your block map (the 2d array) is just a set of references to those 32x32 sprites. If your block map is 16 bit ints, you can use top 8 bits as Y and lower as X, then just use a bitwise operator to get the x and y references into your sprite map.

Drawing the whole map every frame is not what you do for animating the screen, if that's what you mean. You only render the new incoming rows or vertical bars off screen while you pan the screen bitmap. Your visible screen will always be a bar/row or two smaller than the bitmap you are rendering.